# Yii form inside jquery dialog box showing on the page once loaded and not inside the dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have been working through this [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/561/ajax-login-form-with-validation-errors-inside-jquery-modal-dialog/) on yii. The form is supposed to open inside a jquery dialog box, but instead its opening as soon as the page loads and not in the dialog box.

Playing around with it, i found that if i remove the success callback from the ajaxSubmit button, the form opens up in the dialog properly, but is not functioning how its supposed to. Here's the code from the ajaxSubmit button. To see full code [click here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/561/ajax-login-form-with-validation-errors-inside-jquery-modal-dialog/)

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                            'Sign In',
array('/site/login.GetLogin'),
                            array(  
                                'beforeSend' => 'function(){ 
                                                             $("#login").attr("disabled",true);
                                }',
                                'complete' => 'function(){ 
                                     $("#user_login_form").each(function(){ this.reset();});
                                     $("#login").attr("disabled",false);
                                }',
                                'success'=>'function(data){  
                                         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
                                        // View login errors!
                                        // alert(data);
                                         if(obj.login == "success"){
                                            $("#user_login_form").html("<h4>
                                            Login Successful! Please Wait...</h4>
                                            ");
                                            parent.location.href = "/";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $("#login-error-div").show();
                                            $("#login-error-div").html("Login failed! Try again.");$("#login-error-div").append("
                                            ");
                                         }

                                    }', 
),
                     array("id"=>"login","class" => "btn btn-primary")      
            ); ?>
```

Comment: Are u saying you found the fix ?

Comment: no. It opens properly, but not functioning.

Comment: you have to create the ajax submit button as its supposed to and look in Firefox firebug console for javascript errors

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the ajax submit button as its supposed to and look in Firefox firebug console for javascript errors and

Make sure you have set this :

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
    'id'=>'login-dialog',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Login',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
    ),
));?>
```

With

### 'autoOpen'=>false,

Comment: This is set to false. It opens on the page statically as if the dialog box is not there. I will check for javascript errors